# High level problem on probability

Tags: probability

> Let there be two numbers with common divisor $G$ and common multiple $M$ such that
>   $$M=Gab^2c^3d^4$$
>   where $a,b,c,d$ are prime numbers. Find probability that $G$ is GCD and $M$ is LCM of the two numbers

Comment: What's the "probability" distribution? Is it the "natural density" or what?

Comment: sorry, what is the probability space here? Are the numbers chosen uniformly at random form those multiples of $G$ which also divide $M$?  Is $G$ supposed to be prime to $abcd$?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It isn't clear what is varying, nor according to what probability distribution.  Also, you should specify whether the primes $a,b,c,d$ are assumed to be distinct and whether $\gcd (G,abcd)$ is assumed to be $1$.

Comment: Only this much information is given in the question and I think abcd are distinct and gcd(G,abcd) can be anything

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of guesswork involved in reading this problem.

I'll assume that the two numbers are chosen uniformly at random from the $5!$ numbers of the form $$Ga^ib^jc^kd^l$$  where $0≤i≤1,\, 0≤j≤2,\,0≤k≤3,\,0≤\ell≤4$

thus there are $120^2$ possible pairs of the two numbers.

I will also assume that the primes are distinct, though that is not stated.

How many of them have $\gcd=G$ and $\operatorname{lcm} =M$?

Well we need each prime to appear (to its maximal power) in exactly one of the factors.  Thus each number is defined by a subset of $\{a,b,c,d\}$. To illustrate, suppose the subset is $\{a,c,d\}$.  Then your first number is $Gac^3d^4$ and your second is $Gb^2$.

There are $2^4=16$ such subsets so there are $16$ suitable pairs of numbers.

Thus your answer is $$\frac {16}{(120)^2}=\boxed {\frac 1{900}}$$